# How can one create an array of ones in BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Is there a way to create an array of ones (or anything else) of a given length in Google BigQuery? E.g. like `[1]*7` in python, producing the list `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`.

The GENERATE_ARRAY(start, end, step) function cannot be used for this.

I have data given to me as a frequency table and would like to expand out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below

```sql
-- i.e. [1]*7
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 7))) ones;
```